# Is it possible to add items to legend that are not on the chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a column chart in SSRS with a single series group.  The chart is perfect but I need to add a couple of items to the legend even though they are not part of the chart (don't ask).  If I add them to the data source with 0 values, the width of my columns still change to reflect the new number of items in my series group.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Word to create an image of the proper legend and using this image as my legend.  Works great but feels like duct tape.